# how to show list image in gallery?

Tags: gallery

i has create galley in post as: `[gallery columns="6" link="file" ids="156,113,99,67,103,102"]`

Now, how to show list image in `[gallery columns="6" link="file" ids="156,113,99,67,103,102"]` in to index as:

```
<a href="#" title=""><img src="link image in gallery">
.....
<a href="#" title=""><img src="link image in gallery">
```

Any idea give me!

Thanks

Comment: Please expand your question, it's not clear to me what you mean by "show list image". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use `get_post_gallery_images` function, this is example from documentation below

```
function pw_show_gallery_image_urls( $content ) {

global $post;

// Only do this on singular items
if( ! is_singular() )
    return $content;

// Make sure the post has a gallery in it
if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
    return $content;

// Retrieve the first gallery in the post
$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );

$image_list = '<ul>';

// Loop through each image in each gallery
foreach( $gallery as $image_url ) {

    $image_list .= '<li>' . '<img src="' . $image_url . '">' . '</li>';

}

$image_list .= '</ul>';

// Append our image list to the content of our post
$content .= $image_list;

return $content;

 }
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'pw_show_gallery_image_urls' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery_images

Comment: your code is show all for gallery. how to show one gallery ?? i want show one gallery in index. as your code ?

Comment: By this code you get gallery from certain post.

Comment: give me code show list image `[gallery columns="6" link="file" ids="156,113,99,67,103,102"]` in index? i don't show it's?

Answer (score 0):

You can add below shortcode using any file.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="6" link="file" ids="156,113,99,67,103,102"]'); ?>
```

Comment: how to show image as:`<a href="#" title=""><img src="link image in gallery">.....<a href="#" title=""><img src="link image in gallery">` `echo do_shortcode` is easy code.

Comment: For this you have to add any custom field plugin like **Custom Field Suite** and add image in loop than get the values or id from that and add it into <img src="">